# Error during conversion column pandas data frame python 3

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, valueerror

I have a big problem with pandas. I have an important data frame containing

```
Ref_id   PRICE    YEAR  MONTH BRAND
100000   '5000'  '2012' '4'   'FORD'
100001   '10000' '2015' '5'   'MERCEDES'
...
```

I want to convert my PRICE, YEAR and MONTH columns but when I use .astype(int) or .apply(lambda x : int(x)) on the column I receive an ValueError. The length of my data frame is 1.8 million on rows.

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'PRICE'
```

So I don't understand why pandas wants to convert the name of the column.

Could you explain me why ?

Best,

C.

Comment: Please post raw data and full code that reproduces this error

Comment: Sorry I can't, my data and code are confidential so I cannot share them. I can just show you a dataset (test) and the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [59]: cols = 'PRICE  YEAR  MONTH'.split()

In [60]: cols
Out[60]: ['PRICE', 'YEAR', 'MONTH']

In [61]: for c in cols:
    ...:     df[c] = pd.to_numeric(df[c], errors='coerce')
    ...:

In [62]: df
Out[62]:
   Ref_id    PRICE  YEAR  MONTH     BRAND
0  100000   5000.0  2012      4      FORD
1  100001  10000.0  2015      5  MERCEDES
2  100002      NaN  2016      6      AUDI
```

Reproducing your error:

```
In [65]: df
Out[65]:
   Ref_id  PRICE  YEAR  MONTH     BRAND
0  100000   5000  2012      4      FORD
1  100001  10000  2015      5  MERCEDES
2  100002  PRICE  2016      6      AUDI  # pay attention at `PRICE` value !!!

In [66]: df['PRICE'].astype(int)
...
skipped
...
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'PRICE'
```

As [@jezrael has added in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367651/error-during-conversion-column-pandas-data-frame-python-3/43367847?noredirect=1#comment73799183_43367847) most probably you have "bad" (unexpected) values in your data set.

You can use one of the following techniques in order clean it up:

```
In [155]: df
Out[155]:
   Ref_id  PRICE  YEAR  MONTH     BRAND
0  100000   5000  2012      4      FORD
1  100001  10000  2015      5  MERCEDES
2  Ref_id  PRICE  YEAR  MONTH     BRAND
3  100002  15000  2016      5      AUDI

In [156]: df.dtypes
Out[156]:
Ref_id    object
PRICE     object
YEAR      object
MONTH     object
BRAND     object
dtype: object

In [157]: df = df.drop(df.loc[df.PRICE == 'PRICE'].index)

In [158]: df
Out[158]:
   Ref_id  PRICE  YEAR MONTH     BRAND
0  100000   5000  2012     4      FORD
1  100001  10000  2015     5  MERCEDES
3  100002  15000  2016     5      AUDI

In [159]: for c in cols:
     ...:     df[c] = pd.to_numeric(df[c], errors='coerce')
     ...:

In [160]: df
Out[160]:
   Ref_id  PRICE  YEAR  MONTH     BRAND
0  100000   5000  2012      4      FORD
1  100001  10000  2015      5  MERCEDES
3  100002  15000  2016      5      AUDI

In [161]: df.dtypes
Out[161]:
Ref_id    object
PRICE      int64
YEAR       int64
MONTH      int64
BRAND     object
dtype: object
```

or simply:

```
In [159]: for c in cols:
     ...:     df[c] = pd.to_numeric(df[c], errors='coerce')
     ...:

In [165]: df
Out[165]:
   Ref_id    PRICE    YEAR  MONTH     BRAND
0  100000   5000.0  2012.0    4.0      FORD
1  100001  10000.0  2015.0    5.0  MERCEDES
2  Ref_id      NaN     NaN    NaN     BRAND
3  100002  15000.0  2016.0    5.0      AUDI
```

and then `.dropna(how='any')` if you know that there were no `NaN`'s in your original data set:

```
In [166]: df = df.dropna(how='any')

In [167]: df
Out[167]:
   Ref_id    PRICE    YEAR  MONTH     BRAND
0  100000   5000.0  2012.0    4.0      FORD
1  100001  10000.0  2015.0    5.0  MERCEDES
3  100002  15000.0  2016.0    5.0      AUDI
```

Comment: Idea - maybe problem is columns names are mixed with data, you can add test code where are bad data.

Comment: Hi all,
Thanks for your reply and help. The errors='coerce' permit to pass away. But, after different try in iPython, my column PRICE donc contain the word 'PRICE' so I don't know why this error. 
So the method work well, a big thank you for that !!

Comment: @jezrael, i've added your idea to the answer ;)